# Case and Nested Table in Data Mining

Tags: ssas, data-mining, sql-server-2008-express

I have very simple Question. Please can anyone explain with example the Case Table and Nested Table in Data Mining.

I am using SQL Server 2008R2 SSAS and I am confused with Case Table and Nested Table.

If there is any tutorial, Please share.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been struggling with the same problem. Please see this explanation from Microsoft. It helped me a lot.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175659.aspx

Answer (score 2):

A case table is the one which should contain all the cases necessary for your predictions.
So for example you have a scenario in which you want to predict the probability of customers who have bought your product say, a Nokia handset. Now there are lot of assumptions you will be requiring such as gender,income,age etc. And the table which will contain this values are generally used for case table.

Answer (score 0):

A nested table is represented in the case table as a special column that has a data type of TABLE. For any particular case row, this kind of column contains selected rows from the child table that pertain to the parent table.